Top-N recommender system
Say an intermediary is using a two part recommender model that attempts to facilitate services between its clients and external vendors:
Model 1: Predict probability of vendor bidding on a given service sought for the client: $\Pr(\text{Bid})$
Model 2: Predict probability that a vendor will be the winning bidder given that they placed the initial bid: $\Pr(\text{Win}|\text{Bid})$
Then predict $\Pr(\text{Bid and Win})$:
$$
\begin{align}
\Pr(\text{Bid and Win}) &= \Pr(\text{Bid}) \times \Pr(\text{Win}|\text{Bid}) \\
&= \text{output of model 1} \times \text{output of model 2}
\end{align}
$$
Then sort the top-N vendors with the highest predicted $\Pr(\text{Bid and Win})$ as candidates to pursue further and attempt to match with the client's service needs.
Now say an external evaluation criteria is imposed to give a green light to the entire modeling framework:
Is the winning vendor recommended by the modeling framework at least X% of time in the top-N.  (as evaluated over a test dataset).
(the exact % is irrelevant here, could be 5% could be 95%)
Also note that the position within the top-N does not matter. All that matters that the chosen vendor was somewhere in the top-N.
Question: Does getting the top-N with the highest predicted $\Pr(\text{Bid and Win})$ optimize this external criteria? If it does, how might one go about proving this?
